# MVC5: Use updated Session value in View

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I have a MVC5 application in which I am updating the Session["value"] on the click of a button using a ajax call to the server. But after that, accessing the Session["value"] from View doesn't contain the new value. I tried ViewBag also - same thing. Any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty obvious behavior when you consider how things work. The principle in play here is called client-server. The client requests the web page, the server responds with the web page. The values of `Session` and `ViewBag` you're referencing are included at this time in their current state. At some later point in time, the client issues another request, via AJAX, that the server responds to by setting a new value in `Session`/`ViewBag`. This doesn't change what's already been sent to client in the initial request, the web page. You would have to refresh the website in the browser to see the new values.